# How to make list of sections automatically?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

Good afternoon

I have got pages and on every page I have got `\section*{...text...}`. I would like to make list of these sections with name and number of page. Can I do it automatically? Just one imperative.

Do you know it?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm,    
bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy


\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{A}}
\newpage

\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{B}}
\newpage

\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{C}}
\newpage

\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{D}}
\newpage

\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{E}}
\newpage


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, why are you using the starred version? `\section{A}`  would be automatically printed using `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: Numbers of `section` are big and don't look well. And I need list of contents in Slovak no English.

Comment: You can suppress the numbers with \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

Comment: But it's in English - I want to have got it in Slovak.

Comment: Is your whole document going to be slovak? Main language seems to be english.

Comment: @ĽubomírMasarovič : it's because of `main=english` in your options for `babel`. You should thus change the language outside of the command.

Comment: English and Slovak but headlines are Slovak.

Comment: @ĽubomírMasarovič: Why are you using `\section*` all the time and `book` as document class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is a possible solution, using a `\section*{foo}*` variant defined with `xparse`'s `\NewDocumentCommand` -- the syntax is unusual, but the normal `\section*` is preserved then.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm,    
bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{xparse}
\providecommand{\phantomsection}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@section\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{soms}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \IfBooleanT{#4}{%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{{#3}}%
    }%
    \latex@@section*{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \latex@@section[#2]{#3}%
    }{%
      \latex@@section{#3}%
    }
  }%
}    


\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy


\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{A}}*
\newpage

\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{sobota}}*
\newpage

\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{nedel'a}}*
\newpage

\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{D}}*
\newpage

\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{E}}*
\newpage


\end{document}
```

[image]